# Symfony2 extremely slow loading pages

Tags: symfony

Guys i have problem in dev env. My page loading is extremely slow, after refreshing page i must wait 10-15 sec. I just try to show page without any database query just simple html/css layout, MS is 8-10k+ (10000+ ms). I have installed APC and disable automatic assetic generation in config.yml

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
     #bundles:        ['ISLabEcommerceBundle']
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

This only happens when I use assets for my css files. When i disable assets and dont load css files from web dir all pages is loaded to fast.

```
   {% stylesheets 'bundles/islabecommerce/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

Could not work under this environment

Any tip how can i incres loading speed ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest dumping your assets. You can read about it in [symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment)

Comment: **1** First of all minify all js files **2** second thing if you have used long hierarchies in css selectors then remove them and instead of them define simple class.  While writing a selector we write and read it from left to right, but browser engine read selectors from right to left. Browser first, looks for the children and then checks for the parents. so it goes very costly when you have 2 or more levels in selectors. i.e _#div1 #div1_1 .myclass_  **3** if possible then minify css file as well, no harm in that, while working locally - use original file - while uploading - minify it. :)